# how to properly list child pages in sidebar?

Tags: child-pages, wp-list-pages

My pages menu is maximum 3 levels deep and I am having a hard time figuring out how to properly list the child pages in the sidebar.

If a page is a parent I want to list it's direct child pages and the title should be this parent.

If a page is a child AND has children of itself, I want to list only it's children and the title should be this page

If a page is a grandchild, I want to list it's siblings and the title should be this grandchild.

For now I am using (from the Codex):

```
<?php if($post->post_parent) {
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&depth=1&sortcolumn=menuorder");
} else {
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&depth=1&sortcolumn=menuorder");
}
?>
<?php if ($children) { ?>
<div class="left-bar-content">
<h2><?php _e('More ','sunchine') ?><?php echo get_the_title($post->post_parent);?></h2>
<ul class="leftbar-list">
<?php echo $children;?>
</ul>
</div><!-- .left-bar-content -->
<?php
}
?>
```

And this is almost correct. Almost, because my it doesn't do my 2nd criterium.

The Codex has heaps of options, but I cannot figure out which would be applicable to what I want to accomplish. Using widgets and/or a plugin is not an option.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that satisfies all your 3 requirements above.

```
<?php
/*
 * get_page_depth
 * Gets the page depth, calls get_post on every iteration
 * https://gist.github.com/1039575
 */
if ( !function_exists( 'get_page_depth' ) ) {
function get_page_depth( $id=0, $depth=0 ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $id == 0 ) 
        $id = $post->ID;

    $page = get_post( $id );
    if ( !$page->post_parent ) {
            // this page does not have any parent
            return $depth;
    }
    return get_page_depth( $page->post_parent, $depth+1 );
}
}

$target_page = get_page_depth( $post->ID ) > 1 ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of={$target_page}&depth=1&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order");

?>

<div class="left-bar-content">
    <h2><?php _e('More ','sunchine'); ?><?php echo get_the_title( $target_page ); ?></h2>
    <ul class="leftbar-list">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
</div><!-- .left-bar-content -->
```

Comment: this is almost perfect indeed. The only thing that does not go correct is when on a grand child, it should show the title of the direct parent, not the the title of the grandchild (which it shows now) and not the title of the ancestor. So basically when the title is echoed, it should be `$post->ID` for criteria 1 and 2, but `$post->post_parent`for criterium 3... The output in the sidebar is already what it should be so many thanks for that already!

Comment: fix the code, note the change in get_the_title. It should now show parent title on grandchild page.

Comment: Khan, yes Sir! Thank you so much, this total works! And sorry, I re-read my original question and I think I mixed it up myself about the 3rd criterium...

Comment: @Piet, you are always welcome. :)