# Display child pages in sidebar of parent page in wordpress

Tags: pages, child-pages

How to get displayed child pages on parent page and also on child page of that parent in sidebar?Trying to paste code from wp codex page and from several other sites, but with no success.I always get instead of list of child pages, list of parent pages!?
what is the problem?Just to mention, maybe is important, all parent pages have its own page-template.

example code:

```
    <?php
    if($post->post_parent)
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); else
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
   if ($children) { ?>
<ul>
<?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

I also try [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20662/how-to-properly-list-child-pages-in-sidebar/20669#20669) which seems to me doing god job, but again I got list of parent pages

Comment: assuming that the page templates are having a custom query, have you restored the original querystring by adding `wp_reset_query();` after the custom loop? you can check if the sidebar gets the page ID by adding this before your code: `<?php echo $post; ?>`

Comment: also try to add `global $post;` before your code, considering you are using it in a textwidget with the 'exec php' plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a *list of Pages*, then why are you calling `wp_list_pages()` in your code? that function returns a *list of Pages*.

You probably [need to use `get_posts()` instead](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), and then loop through the results to output whatever `$post` content you want to display.

e.g. you could do something like the following:

```
<?php
global $post;
$child_pages = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
) );
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ( $child_pages as $child ) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <h3><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></h3>
        <div><?php echo $child->post_content; ?></div>
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

If you need to access `$post->ID` from outside the Loop, do something like this *inside* the Loop:

```
$current_post_id = $post->post_ID;
```

Then, just use `$current_post_id` outside the Loop. (Note that you'll only want to do this on template pages that display single Posts; otherwise, the value of `$current_post_id` will change on every cycle of the `foreach` loop.)

You could then change your `get_posts()` call accordingly:

```
$child_pages = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent' => $current_post_id
) );
```

Comment: That gives me no output at all.Blank...

Comment: It is example code, that needs to be adapted to your specific use case. If you're outside the Loop, you may need to set a variable *inside* the Loop, to hold `$post->ID`, so that you can access it outside the Loop.

Comment: yes, Im ouside the loop, text widget with exec plugin.My needs is to display childpages on specific parent page, and also on childpages from current parent page in sidebar.To set variable inside a loop for this specific case is too much for my level of php and wp.Can you help me little closer on this?
tnx

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: I got something, but now Im confused, I put variable inside the loop of my one page template file, but now I got displayed some post with content instead of childpages titles.I got this on every page same also, no metter that Im put variable in just one page template.I got several different page templates for my Pages?

Comment: Okay, can you edit your question to clarify *exactly what you want to display* in the sidebar, what kind of templates you have created for your Child Pages (full template files, or template part files)? (Note that you really can't - and shouldn't - include a full Page template inside of another Page template.) Any additional information you can provide will be helpful.

Comment: Ok.
First, I did not created any template for child pages.I created standard page template for my PARENT pages, eg. Home page, got home page template; about page, got about page template.Every childpage share same page template with assosiated parent page.Im hope thats clear?

I want to list all the child pages in my sidebar for specific parent page(eg.About page have child pages Me, MyDog, MyCAt, iwant to show this subpages in sidebar of About page only)
I want the child pages to show even while on another child page of the same parent page.

tnx

Comment: But *what* do you want to display? Page Titles? Page content? What?

Comment: links to child pages.Something like submenu

Comment: My question is still confused ?

Comment: Is it not possible?

Comment: You need to add 'post_type' => 'page' to the get_posts() array.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: notice the use of depth in the child `wp_list_pages`.

```
<?php 
    if($post->post_parent)
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&depth=1&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>

   <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I am using

```
<?php
   if ($post->post_parent)  {
        $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
        $root=count($ancestors)-1;
        $parent = $ancestors[$root];
    } else {
        $parent = $post->ID;
    }
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=". $parent ."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul class="tabs vertical hide-on-phones three columns">
        <li>Hekki</li>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

I want the parent page to display as well.

Comment: Is this -- "I want the parent page to display as well." -- a question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <ul class="sidenav">
    <?php
    if($post->post_parent)
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>          
    </ul>
```

Comment: its code from my question??

Comment: If you look closely, it's slightly different. I use this snippet quite often and it shows parent + child pages on parent page + child page of that parent.

Comment: Same output:-(->list of parent pages?huh
I put this in sidebar widget, and all my pages have its own page template, just to notice.Maybe is important, Im pretty stack in this issue...